# SQL - Search a table for all instances where a value is repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm looking to find a way to search a table for duplicate values and return those duplicates (or even just one of the set of duplicates) as the result set.

For instance, let's say I have these data:

```
uid    |   semi-unique id
1      |       12345
2      |       21345
3      |       54321
4      |       41235
5      |       12345
6      |       21345
```

I need to return either:

```
12345
12345
21345
21345
```

Or:

```
12345
21345
```

I've tried googling around and keep coming up short. Any help please?

Comment: My SQL's a bit rusty...but can't you get this with a self-join and a group by?

Comment: @Droogans you don't need a self-join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get each row, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by [semi-unique id]) as totcnt
      from t
     ) t
where totcnt > 1
```

To get just one instance, try this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by [semi-unique id]) as totcnt,
             row_number() over (partition by [semi-unique id] order by (select NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where totcnt > 1 and seqnum = 1
```

The advantage of this approach is that you get all the columns, instead of just the id (if that helps).

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. They both worked like charms. Alas, I have to pick one as the answer and, after careful consideration, I will pick the one that uses window functions as it can be adapted in many ways (and showing the values of the other columns does help me). Thanks again to you both, though. I would accept both answers if I could and I did upvote both.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I was short on time earlier so I couldn't explain my answer.  The first query groups the semi_unique_ids that are the same and only returns the ones that have a duplicate.

```
SELECT semi_unique_id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY semi_unique_id
HAVING COUNT(semi_unique_id) > 1
```

If you wanted to get the uid in the query too you can easily add it like so.

```
SELECT uid,
       semi_unique_uid
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY
       semi_unique_id,
       uid
HAVING COUNT(semi_unique_id) > 1
```

Lastly if you would like to get an idea of how many duplicates per row returned you would do the following.

```
SELECT uid,
       semi_unique_uid,
       COUNT(semi_unique_uid) AS unique_id_count
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY
       semi_unique_id,
       uid
HAVING COUNT(semi_unique_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. They both worked like charms. Alas, I have to pick one as the answer and, after careful consideration, I will pick the one that uses window functions as it can be adapted in many ways (and showing the values of the other columns does help me). Thanks again to you both, though. I would accept both answers if I could and I did upvote both.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.semi_unique_id AS i
FROM   TABLE t
GROUP BY
       t.semi_unique_id
HAVING (COUNT(t.semi_unique_id) > 1)
```

> Try this for sql-server